# Adding ng-app attribute via Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to add the ng-app attribute to the body tag using JQuery in hopes that the  Angular Controller will take over after that.  However, I am seeing that does not work.  Is this possible?  If so what needs be set for this to work?  [Plunker Code Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qc6ssrDV89kqmdh3jS06?p=preview)

```
  <script>

    jQuery.noConflict();
      (function( $ ) {
        $(function() {
          $('body').attr('ng-app',changeExample');
        });
      })(jQuery);

    angular.module('changeExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          var rawData = JSON.parse(data); // web  service call
          $scope.SearchResults = rawData.ResultRows;


          $scope.ProjectSelected = function(proj) {

            $scope.SelectedProj = proj;
            $('input#originalSPTexbox').val(proj);
          };

        }
      ]);
  </script>
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap - `angular.bootstrap(document, ['changeExample']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("body").attr("ng-app", "changeExample");
```

I just added this in front of the data variable declaration on plunker and that seemed to have worked fine(and I obviously removed the ng-app attribute from the body tag).

Hopefully that helps.

I just added a missing quote on changeExample, and I moved the script to the bottom of the page so the body tag will have been loaded so you can add the attribute.

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/IPt1mI8Aw0XQ1bz8Mrqm?p=preview][1]
```

Comment: I think we are working on the wrong plunker. I'll have to update it so it is correct.